# how come I have so many versions of nodejs?

Tags: node.js, windows, bash, cmd

how come I have so many versions of nodejs.

I have multiple of command prompts applications, I have
1. nodejs cmd
2. ubunto bash cmd
3. my normal cmd
and a bunch of others but I dont use them..

my question is.
1.how do I update my nodejs in my system and be just automatically reflected on all of my cmd's? is that even possible?
2. why is this happening?
3. what cmd should I use for running node applications?

below are the snapshots of cmds and the result that it gave me when I checked the version of node.

[image: Command prompt]

[image: node cmd]

[image: bash]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> 1. how do I update my nodejs in my system and be just automatically reflected on all of my cmd's?
> 2. why is this happening?

You can install node.js globally, you have different versions because you didn't install globally, so your cmds can't be automatically reflected. You can see this blog how to install node.js globally:
[How To Install Node.js on Ubuntu 16.04](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-node-js-on-ubuntu-16-04)

> 3. what cmd should I use for running node applications?

you can run node applications using cmd which you want, it doesn't matter.

Answer (score 3):

Right off the bat, I can tell you that the **only nodejs package actually installed globally on your system is the first image you have shown (`v6.10.2`)**.

The second image (`v6.11.2`) came with the **nodejs installer**. So if you uninstall that application, you will not see it again. Check your `PATH` variable to make sure.

The third image (`v4.2.6`) is installed on **`WSL`** and therefore lives some place separate from the rest of your windows files and programs. You can use the command `apt-get remove --purge nodejs` to remove that one.

---

To answer your question, you cannot have the same nodejs across all systems because as you can see from my answer above, these versions of nodejs live in separate environments which are contained.

#### I would recommend using the nodejs installation from [nodejs.org](https://nodejs.org/en/download/) for running nodejs. This is the same as your second image.

**Did you know windows has a package manager?** Try [chocolatey](https://chocolatey.org/) for managing [node](https://chocolatey.org/search?q=nodejs) versions.

Comment: If first thought that this is a strang way to place an advertisemnt for food :D I never have heard of that package manger before.

Comment: @t.niese Lol. I was hesitant to leave it just like that, but decided to just go with it; someone was bound to be curious enough to find out what it was all about

Answer (score -1):

You can use nvm to manage and easily switch between node's versions.